# Why are results in the browser using Google AutoML so different from an exported tflite file in my android app?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-cloud-automl, tensorflow-lite

I'm training a model using Google AutoML. I then exported a TFLite model to run on an android app.

With the same image used in the app and in the browser (Google AutoML gives you a chance to test your model in the browser), I get a very accurate answer in the browser but in my app, I get a not-so accurate answer.

Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Relevant code:

```
  public void predict(String imagePath, final Promise promise) {
    imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    labelProbArray = new byte[1][RESULTS_TO_SHOW];

    try {

      labelList = loadLabelList();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.w("FIND_ ", imagePath);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap);


    try {
      tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Log.w("FIND_exception in loading tflite", "1");      
    }

    tflite.run(imgData, labelProbArray);
    promise.resolve(getResult());
  }


  private WritableNativeArray getResult() {
    WritableNativeArray result = new WritableNativeArray();

    //ArrayList<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    try {

      for (int i = 0; i < RESULTS_TO_SHOW; i++) {
          WritableNativeMap map = new WritableNativeMap();

          map.putString("label", Integer.toString(i));
          float output = (float)(labelProbArray[0][i] & 0xFF) / 255f;
          map.putString("prob", String.valueOf(output));
          result.pushMap(map);

          Log.w("FIND_label ", Integer.toString(i));
          Log.w("FIND_prob ", String.valueOf(labelProbArray[0][i]));
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
  }

  private List<String> loadLabelList() throws IOException {
    Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
      List<String> labelList = new ArrayList<String>();
      BufferedReader reader =
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open(LABEL_PATH)));
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          labelList.add(line);
      }
      reader.close();
      return labelList;
  }

  private void convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
      if (imgData == null) {
          return;
      }
      imgData.rewind();
      Log.w("FIND_bitmap width ", String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()));
      Log.w("FIND_bitmap height ", String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

      bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
      // Convert the image to floating point.
      int pixel = 0;
      //long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
      for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_X; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
              final int val = intValues[pixel++];

              imgData.put((byte) ( ((val >> 16) & 0xFF)));
              imgData.put((byte) ( ((val >> 8) & 0xFF)));
              imgData.put((byte) ( (val & 0xFF)));
              Log.w("FIND_i", String.valueOf(i));
              Log.w("FIND_j", String.valueOf(j));
          }
      }
  }

  private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
    Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd(MODEL_PATH);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
  }
```

One of the things I don't know if is correct is how I adjust my output data into a probability. In the `getResult()` method, I write this:

`float output = (float)(labelProbArray[0][i] & 0xFF) / 255f;`

I divide by 255 in order to get a number between 0 and 1, but I don't know if this is correct.

The .tflite model is a quantized uint8 model if that helps.

Comment: Can you please share the code which you are using to process the image before inference on Android?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I just posted some relevant methods that I use to make a prediction. These methods include loading the model, processing the image, and getting the results. Let me know if I should add anymore details.

Comment: Are you normalizing the pixel values by dividing them by 255?

Comment: do you mean in the convertBitmapToByteBuffer method? Ie, where where I say "              imgData.put((byte) ( ((val >> 16) & 0xFF)));"? I'm not normalizing. I'm just writing the unsigned pixel value. Is dividing by 255 there needed?

Comment: In most of the models, the pixel value values are normalized so the gradients don't explode while training. Which model have you trained on AutoML

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal a simple classifier. Regarding the comment of "pixel value values are normalized so the gradients don't explode", are you saying that because this normalization is happening during training our model, that any inputs we test with should also be normalized?

Comment: Yes, as the model is trained on normalized values. It is very general practice and probably the model you created will have been trained on normalized values only.